# Getting field labels from the $node variable

Tags: 7, entities

How can I get the labels of specific fields within a node, in Drupal 7?

The field for which I am interested has the following structure:

```
    [field_text_question1] => Array(
      [und] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
          [value] => Sales Intern
          [format] => 
          [safe_value] => Sales Intern
        ) 
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 13):

The best way is to use [field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) to get information about specific instace of a field. The label of the field is contained in the array returned from that function.

```
 $info = field_info_instance('node','field_name','content_type_name');
 print $info['label'];
```

Comment: i need to use the field_name but with entity translation can i ? 
i tried that but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking inside the `$node`variable.   It is not available there.  Only the field values are store inside the `$node` variable not the field settings (such as the label).   If you want the label look in the `$content` variable.

`$content` variable is available in the `MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variable)` theme template function, `node.tpl.php`, as well as, a few others.

If it is not available, you can call `field_info_field($field_name)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to print the field label of a node is:

```
<?php print $content['field_your_field_name']['#title']; ?>
```

(I've discovered it after a lot of print_r arrays and objects of Drupal! If it's so easy, why isn't explained anywhere, or why is so hidden that I've not found the trick? And passed a long time from the question to this answer...)