# How can I get the labels of values of a field?

Tags: entities

I have created a List (text) field that has key|label pairs as options. How do I get the label, when the key is what is stored in the node?

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
  if (isset($node->field_k_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
    $info = (field_info_field('field_k_status'));
    $status =  $info['settings']['allowed_values'][$node->field_k_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']];
  } else {
    $status = "Not Set";
  }
```

At this point, `$status` will have the label of whatever `field_k_status` is set to.
[field_info_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) gets the details about the field, and `$node->field_k_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` gets the value. I think that there is likely a better way, but I couldn't find it. There is a somewhat similar question asked [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/getting-field-labels-from-the-node-variable), but I didn't find what I was looking for anywhere else.