# How to display custom field label added by CCK in node.tpl file?

Tags: entities, theming

I have a new content type called **hotel** and have added a field called **timing**. For display in node.tpl.php, I can use **field_view_value()** but how do I get the value for the label. I know I can use the $content array, but is there a standard Drupal way or function to achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting field labels from the $node variable](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/getting-field-labels-from-the-node-variable)

Comment: Johnathan, Thank you very much.I had tried to search a lot but could not get the answer. Also apologies for posting a repetitive question.